# Access to PayPayl's phone validation?

Tags: api, validation, paypal, phone-number

PayPal seems to have a very intensive and through check for the legitimacy of phone numbers. More than just having the right number of digits, it seems to check for true area codes and more. Does paypal have some api where I can submit a phone number and it returns if it's considered valid or not?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any API like this through PayPal that you would be able to use to validate a phone number.